# 4 instances of jCarousel, only the last one works

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I am working on http://staticstore.cambiumlearning.com/. There is a `#tabInnerContainer` element with four `<ul class="tabItem">` instances, and I am trying to run jCarousel on each one, but only the last instance seems to work! I even tried to initialize them individually by their IDs, but still--only the last one referenced would run!

Sorry if this is too vague; I'll be happy to provide more info if requested. TIA for any help anyone can give me!

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using to initiate the jCarousels? That would help us diagnose what's going wrong.

Comment: Could you try putting up an example of what's happening on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

There's one pair of arrows for each carousel, but your arrows are on top of each other (the last carousel has higher z-index), thats why it's only the last UL that is beeing changed on click.
You should put the "hide"-class on the container of both UL and arrows, and not on the UL itself.

```
function selectTab(thing) {
    $('#tabContainer .tabs a').each(function(index) {
        $(this).removeClass('tabSelected');
    });
    $(thing).addClass('tabSelected');
    $('#tabInnerContainer ul.tabItem').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr('data-category') === $(thing).attr('data-category')) {
            $(this).parent('.jcarousel-skin-tango').removeClass('hide');
            //alert($(this).attr('id') + ' should be visible!');
        } else if ($(this).attr('data-category') != $(thing).attr('data-category')) {
            $(this).parent('.jcarousel-skin-tango').addClass('hide');
        }
    });
}
```